# How to stop ReSharper from inserting unnecessary newline between the assigned variable and the collection initializer

Tags: c#, resharper

Given a collection that exceeds the `Right margin (columns)` setting in ReSharper:

```
var list = new List<string> { "a", "lot", "of", "items" };
```

When I run `Cleanup Code`, it reformats it to this:

```
var list =
    new List<string> {
        "a",
        "lot",
        "of",
        "items"
    };
```

Ideally, I would like it to produce this:

```
var list = new List<string> {
    "a",
    "lot",
    "of",
    "items"
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I know how to do it using the standard C# style of placing that first bracket on its own line under "var" and could probably figure this out, too.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found a solution. It still bothers me to this day.

Comment: I think I could probably get this to work.  I'll try to put together an answer in a bit if time allows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the most recent ReSharper (10).  If not, you can probably look up the wording and placement of the equivalent settings.

Try this:

- Code Editing >> C# >> Formatting Style >> Braces Layout >> Braces Layout >> Array and object initializer (set this to "At end of line (K&R style)")
- Code Editing >> C# >> Formatting Style >> Other >> Indentation >> Continuous line indent multiplier (set this value to 1)
- Code Editing >> C# >> Formatting Style >> Other >> Align Multiline Constructs >> Array, object and collection initializer (UNCHECK this box)
- Code Editing >> C# >> Formatting Style >> Line Breaks and Wrapping >> Line Wrapping >> Wrap object and collection initializer (set to CHOP ALWAYS and do the same for "Wrap array initializer" if you wish)
- Code Editing >> C# >> Formatting Style >> Line Breaks and Wrapping >> Line Wrapping >> Preserve Existing Formatting >> Keep existing line breaks (UNCHECK this box)

I think that last one might be the kicker.  My suspicion is that a default formatting setting in Visual Studio is causing the line break after the assignment operator and ReSharper isn't fixing it because you have that last setting checked.

Also, from an opinion standpoint, I would strongly advise against using that 1st point to keep the opening bracket on the same line (K&R style).  The C# convention is to use the BSD style.  K&R is prevalent in JavaScript and various other languages, but C# doesn't look right to most people when written that way.  Do what you'd like, though!

If this doesn't work for you, let me know and I'll look into it more.

Comment: If you would be so kind, I'm have a [similar formatting issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974595/how-to-stop-resharper-from-inserting-unnecessary-newline-between-the-assigned-va) with ReSharper that might be related to this one.

Comment: @MylesMegyesi - If it's not answered, I'll take a look in a bit once I'm able.