# How to stop ReSharper from inserting unnecessary newline between the assigned variable and chained method call

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a class that has some methods which return `this`, such that I can chain the calls together:

```
public class Person {
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }

   public Person WithFirstName(string firstName) {
       FirstName = firstName;
       return this;
   }

   public Person WithLastName(string lastName) {
       LastName = lastName;
       return this;
   }
}
```

However when I chain enough methods together such that the `Right margin (columns)` setting in ReSharper, the expression is formatted a little funky.

```
var john =
    new Person().WithFirstName("John")
                .WithLastName("Smith")
                .WithLastName("Smith")
                .WithLastName("Smith")
                .WithLastName("Smith");
```

Obviously, the example is a little contrived because I would never just call the same method over and over again, but in my production code I'm interfacing with a Fluent API which is configured by chaining together about 10 method calls.

Ideally, the code would be formatted like this:

```
// on a single line when less characters than `Right margin (columns)`
var john = new Person().WithFirstName("John").WithLastName("Smith");

// aligned at the "." when longer than `Right margin (columns)`
var john = new Person().WithFirstName("John")
                       .WithLastName("Smith")
                       .WithLastName("Smith")
                       .WithLastName("Smith")
                       .WithLastName("Smith");
```

The real question is why ReSharper is putting the whole expression on a new line. Any suggestions?

Comment: What if the class name, instead of `Person`, was: `SomeReallyLongClassNameBecauseImaZombieAndEatScreenRealEstate`? Then where should the `.WithLastName` be aligned?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to control this, at least in R# 10.0.2

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem using Manuel's answer, or some other method?

Comment: Nope, I wasn't able to find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure which one is responsible, you'll have to tweak a bit, but the settings for formatting are placed in Reshaper->Options->Code Editing->C#->Formatting Style->Line breaks and Wrapping. That's at least a good starting point for you !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set "Wrap chained method calls" to "Chop always" so that you get `var john = new Person().WithFirstName("John")` on the same line.

Comment: Yes; it doesn't seem very intuitive, but this is the correct setting to adjust.  When combined with checking the box for Code Editing >> C# >> Formatting Style >> Other >> Align Multiline Constructs >> Chained method calls... you should get the result you're after.  I just did it and it works for me.